# Does Micorsoft teams require special provisioning to improve rate limiting issues?

Tags: microsoft-teams, rate-limiting, http-status-code-429

We are hitting rate limiting issues with Graph APIs usage. Is there any way to upgrade our tenant/membership to improve the performance and response times?

It takes up to minutes, and sometimes APIs not getting processed at all. We require real time response.

Any pointers in this regard will be really helpful.

Thanks
Laksh

```
Request Type : Get Channel messages API using Global Admin credentials is called with 1Second interval
Request URL : GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/${teamId}/channels/${channelId}/messages

const options = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${globalAdminAccessToken}`,
    ‘Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: '*/*'
  }
};

let url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/${teamId}/channels/${channelId}/messages`;

axios
  .get(
     url,
     options
  )
  .then(resp => {
     console.log(resp);
    })
  .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);

});
```

Comment: Plase check this document for handle throttling in graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling. Also could you please confirm if you are handling 429s in your code?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT thanks for your response. We already have implemented throttling mentioned in the link you shared and handling 429 in our application. However even with about 1 API request per sec (and max of 5 requests go in succession with 1 sec gap, total of about 40 calls per day) rejection from MS teams doesnt makes sense. How can we improve the guaranteed response from MS teams? Does that require any special account setup?? This is frustrating

Comment: We are checking this internally. Meanwhile, could you please share the request and response for failed requests?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT please see the revised question that has request & response